# Creating a "popout" nav sidebar in CSS/JS

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to copy a navbar similar to the one on AtmosphereJS's [website](https://atmospherejs.com), for use in my site. How would I go about doing this, especially making the body "popout" and just leaving the navbar on the left. Could someone explain what type of CSS's properties I should use or potentially point me to a jquery plugin or make a codepen with an example.
![atmospherejs navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAtoD.png)

Comment: If you want to do this purely with CSS, you need to start with the `:focus` pseudo-class and a CSS `transform` using `scale` and `translate`...

Comment: I don't know if I should vote to close as "unclear what you are asking", "too broad", or "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic"

Comment: @Oriol what do you suggest adding?

Comment: @adamSiwiec, possibly inspect the site you're trying to emulate and see for yourself how they do it. [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) should be in your toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too broad, I think the term you are looking for is Hamburger menu. Look for that, try to build one and then maybe share your code and ask how to create the transition using javascript.